# How to dynamically sync and instantly show the value in two entries

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to sync the value that I type in Entry1 as soon as I finish typing to Entry2 and immediately showing it in its text. How should I do it?

This is my 1st day to tkinter, I did some searches and yet still have no clue about the usage of StringVar(), or update(), or other ways that would possibly help with the issue.

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x300')
Entry1=tk.Entry(root)
# Don't know what to do here for Entry 1....
Entry2=tk.Entry(root)
Entry2.insert(0,Entry1.get())
# I know nothing will automatically happen in Entry2, but really don't know how to do it....
```

Comment: I know add a "Button" widget would solve the issue and I know how, but just want make it happen 'automatically'.

Comment: How do you want the program to know you have finished typing? Are you interested in a solution that keeps them both in sync while you are typing?

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I'm looking for... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you literally want both entry widgets to always be in sync, you can give them both the same value for the `textvariable` option:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
var = tk.StringVar()
e1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var)
e2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var)

e1.pack(side="top", fill="x")
e2.pack(side="top", fill="x")

root.mainloop()
```